# Having munin server monitoring problem: Graphs not being generated

Tags: linux, monitoring, performance-monitoring, munin

When I run munin-cron (`munin-cron --debug`), I get the following error:

```
2010/05/10 13:39:01 [WARNING] Call to accept timed out.  Remaining workers: archstl.org;archstl.archstl.org

2010/05/10 13:39:01 [DEBUG] Active workers: 1/8
```

These errors simply keep repeating themselves until I quit munin-cron.

I've followed the directions for debugging munin on the '[Debugging Munin plugins](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Debugging_Munin_plugins)' wiki page, but I get the following results when going through their directions:

After telnetting to localhost 4949, I can see a list of plugins, see a node at archstl.archstl.org, but can't fetch anything. The output is as follows:

```
>fetch cpu
.
```

However, on the same machine (which is both the node and the master munin server), I can run `munin-run cpu`, and it prints the results correctly to the command line, like so:

```
user.value 100829130
nice.value 3479880
system.value 13969362
idle.value 664312639
iowait.value 12180168
irq.value 14242
softirq.value 199526
steal.value 0
```

Looking at the wiki page mentioned above, it looks like it might be a plugin environment problem, but I can't figure out how to fix/change this...

> If the plugin does run with munin-run but not through telnet, you probably have a PATH problem. Tip: Set env.PATH for the plugin in the plugin's environment file.

Comment: Do you get this result for all plugins or just certain ones?

Comment: All plugins... I decided to just use cPanel's pre-built munin package instead of building it on my own :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a permission pb....

1. Can you launch `munin-run cpu` as the same user that runs the munin-node process ?
2. If your system is SELinux/AppArmor enabled, you have to make sure that the processes launched with TTY are also allowed to launch the plugins.

... or something else : does it work with netcat ? Test with a `nc localhost 4949`. Netcat's line-ending handling is different than telnet's.